# Counting Distinct Values in large dataset (40M rows): SELECT count(*) as count, name FROM names GROUP BY name ORDER BY name;

Tags: optimization, dataset, query-optimization

```
CREATE TABLE `names` ( `name` varchar(20) );
```

Assume the `names` table contains all 40 million first names of everyone living in California (for example).

```
SELECT count(*) as count, name FROM names GROUP BY name ORDER BY name;
```

How can I optimize this query?

Expected Result:

```
count | name
 9999 | joe
 9995 | mike
 9990 | kate
 .... | ....
    2 | kal-el
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an index on the name column of your table. The query is as good as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what makes you think it's not already optimised? This looks like the sort of query a good database engine should be able to handle relatively easily - particularly if you've got an appropriate index on your table.

Do you actually have a bottleneck here, or are you worrying about something that *might* happen in the future? If it's the latter, I suggest you try it with your RDBMS (by generating dummy data), and see what happens.